# See FPS gauge on Xcode 13.3.1

Tags: swift, swiftui, frame-rate, xcode-debugger, xcode13.3.1

How can I enable the FPS gauge on Xcode 13.3.1.

Inside debug navigation I only see

- CPU
- Memory
- Disk
- Network

I know that in previous versions of Xcode there was FPS option...

I am running the Universel app with SwiftUI. (Try both mac and iPad simulator)

Comment: If you want to see more info, Xcode will only show that stuff - you could try using Instruments, which will show a lot more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation clearly says that FPS only appears when you use a real device, not on the simulator.

*There are seven types of debug gauges: CPU, Memory, Energy, Disk I/O, Network I/O, FPS, and iCloud. But not all of these gauges appear for all types of apps. **For example, the Energy, FPS, and iCloud gauges only appear when you run your app on a real device**. The FPS gauge only appears for iOS apps. The iCloud gauge only appears when you enable iCloud.*